# How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, unicode

- I decided to make some kind of secret code for testing purposes with Unicode.
- I've done that by adding numbers to Unicode so it would be kind of secret.
- I've been getting this error, but I don't know how to solve it.

  - Is there any solution?

### Original Code

```py
message = input("Enter a message you want to be revealed: ")
secret_string = ""
for char in message:
    secret_string += str(chr(char + 7429146))
print("Revealed", secret_string)
q = input("")
```

### Original Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-49ece294a581> in <module>
      2 secret_string = ""
      3 for char in message:
----> 4     secret_string += str(chr(char + 7429146))
      5 print("Revealed", secret_string)
      6 q = input("")

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

### Updated code

```py
while True:
    try:
        message = int(input("Enter a message you want to be decrypt: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, it must be an integer")
secret_string = ""
for char in message:
    secret_string += chr(ord(char - str(742146)))
print("Decrypted", secret_string)
q = input("")
```

Answer (score 168):

**Python** working a bit differently to JavaScript for example, the value you are concatenating needs to be same type, both **int** or **str**...

So for example the code below **throw an error**:

```
print( "Alireza" + 1980)
```

like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    print( "Alireza" + 1980)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

To solve the issue, just add str to your number or value like:

```
print( "Alireza" + str(1980))
```

And the result as:

```
Alireza1980
```

Answer (score 32):

## Use f-strings to resolve the `TypeError`

- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```py
# the following line causes a TypeError
# test = 'Here is a test that can be run' + 15 + 'times'

# same intent with an f-string
i = 15

test = f'Here is a test that can be run {i} times'

print(test)

# output
'Here is a test that can be run 15 times'
```

```
i = 15
# t = 'test' + i  # will cause a TypeError

# should be
t = f'test{i}'

print(t)

# output
'test15'
```

- The issue may be attempting to evaluate an expression where a variable is the string of a numeric.

  - Convert the string to an `int`.
  - This scenario is specific to this question
- When iterating, it's important to be aware of the `type`

```py
i = '15'
# t = 15 + i  # will cause a TypeError

# convert the string to int
t = 15 + int(i)
print(t)

# output
30
```

### Note

- The preceding part of the answer addresses the `TypeError` shown in the question title, which is why people seem to be coming to this question.
- However, this doesn't resolve the issue in relation to the example provided by the OP, which is addressed below.

## Original Code Issues

- `TypeError` is caused because `type(message) → str`.

  - The code iterates each character and attempts to add `char`, a `str` type, to an `int`
  - That issue can be resolved by converting `char` to an `int`
  - As the code is presented, `secret_string` needs to be initialized with `0` instead of `""`.
- The code also results in a `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)` because `7429146` is out of range for `chr()`.

  - Resolved by using a smaller number
- The output is not a string, as was intended, which leads to the Updated Code in the question.

```py
message = input("Enter a message you want to be revealed: ")

secret_string = 0

for char in message:
    char = int(char)
    value = char + 742146
    secret_string += ord(chr(value))
    
print(f'\nRevealed: {secret_string}')

# Output
Enter a message you want to be revealed:  999

Revealed: 2226465
```

## Updated Code Issues

- `message` is now an `int` type, so `for char in message:` causes `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

  - `message` is converted to `int` to make sure the `input` is an `int`.
  - Set the type with `str()`
- Only convert `value` to Unicode with [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)

  - Don't use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

```py
while True:
    try:
        message = str(int(input("Enter a message you want to be decrypt: ")))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, it must be an integer")
        
secret_string = ""
for char in message:
    
    value = int(char) + 10000
    
    secret_string += chr(value)

print("Decrypted", secret_string)

# output
Enter a message you want to be decrypt:  999
Decrypted ✙✙✙

Enter a message you want to be decrypt:  100
Decrypted ✑✐✐
```

Answer (score 22):

instead of using " + " operator

```py
print( "Alireza" + 1980)
```

Use comma " , " operator

```py
print( "Alireza" , 1980)
```

Comment: `print( "Alireza" , 1980)` outputs `Alireza 1980` with an extra space between.

Comment: To avoid the extra space it is possible to override the default value of the `sep` argument: `print("Alireza" , 1980, sep='')`

Comment: This only works for `print` since it takes an unlimited number of arguments to print. It doesn't work in the general case of trying to concatenate a string with an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
print("Program for calculating sum")
numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
sum=0
for number in numbers:
    sum += number
print("Total Sum is: %d" %sum )
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you are doing the following

```
str(chr(char + 7429146))
```

where char is a string. You cannot add a int with a string. this will cause that error

maybe if you want to get the ascii code and add it with a constant number. if so , you can just do ord(char) and add it to a number. but again, chr can take values between 0 and 1114112

Answer (score 2):

Change `secret_string += str(chr(char + 7429146))`

To `secret_string += chr(ord(char) + 7429146)`

`ord()` converts the character to its Unicode integer equivalent. `chr()` then converts this integer into its Unicode character equivalent.

Also, 7429146 is too big of a number, it should be less than 1114111