# I received an error message that I don't quite understand

Tags: python

I am working on a program and I received an error message that said:

```
print("I will set a timer for " + shortesttime + "minutes")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I assumed it meant that I had to change the variable from an int to a string but when I tried it it didn't work. Afterwards I just thought that maybe I wasn't understanding the error message correctly.

Here's some code for context:

```
shortesttime = hwt.index(min(hwt))
smallesthwitem = (uhw[hwt.index(min(hwt))]) #it's finding the position of the smallest item in homeworktime and then, for example if the place of that was 2 it would find what's at the second place in uhw
print("So let's start with something easy. First you're going to do " + smallesthwitem)
print("I will set a timer for " + shortesttime + "minutes")
```

Sorry about the weird variable names

Comment: Many examples how to format strings in Python can be foubd on https://pyformat.info/ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/getting-a-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Comment: You were right, you do need to change an int to string.  How did you try it?  What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

The error says that concatenating (with `+`) a string to an integer is not allowed. Other languages (BASIC comes to mind) let you do that. The best thing to do is to use a formatter. If you want a simple formatting, then all you need is:

```
print(f"I will set a timer for {shortesttime} minutes")
```

There's options in formatters to add commas for thousands and other stuff, but this is easier than mucking with type conversions. This format was introduced in python 3.6 (called f-strings). If you are between 3.0 and 3.5 use

```
print("I will set a timer for {} minutes".format(shortesttime))
```

Which is equivalent, just a bit longer and not as clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Always Remember :** To join multiple strings, You perhaps have to strings only. For example, You can't concatenate `int` with `str` .

So to print it you have to convert it to a `string` which is known as `str` in python world.

On the 4th line change it to : `print("I will set a timer for " + str(shortesttime) + "minutes")`

**One more way would be formatted string :**

Like this, `print(f"I will set a timer for {shortesttime} minutes")`. Formatted strings automatically converts any datatype to string.

Comment: This is misleading, as e.g. `print(1.0)` will work just fine and `1.0` is hardly a `str`.

Comment: @norok2 Ohh sorry,I should probably edit the answer. I forgot to mention that `int` cannot be concatenated with the `str`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
print("I will set a timer for " + str(shortesttime) + "minutes")
```

You can cast it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

As @ferdbugs mentioned earlier, you can cast any value to a `string` type.
Your code should look somewhat like this

```
shortesttime = hwt.index(min(hwt))
smallesthwitem = (uhw[hwt.index(min(hwt))]) #it's finding the position of the smallest item in homeworktime and then, for example if the place of that was 2 it would find what's at the second place in uhw
print("So let's start with something easy. First you're going to do " + smallesthwitem)
print("I will set a timer for " + str(shortesttime) + "minutes")
```

Hope this helps! Do let me know in the comments if you still get the same error or a different error.