# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str123

Tags: python

I am getting an error after running the following code.

Here is the code:

```
a=input("enter the string value")
b=int(input("enter the number"))
c=a+b
print(c)
```

Here is result:

```
enter the string value xyz
enter the number 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/python learning/error1.py", line 3, in <module>      
    c=a+b
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/getting-a-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you can't add string value with the different types(int,float,boolean etc).
To get result for this code you have to change one of them either in string type or int type.

```
a=input()
b=input()
c=a+b
print(c)
```

Or

```
 a=int(input("enter the number"))
    b=int(input("enter the number"))
    c=a+b
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can't add a string to an int. To do so, you can use a different method such as `format`:

```
a = input("enter the string value")
b = int(input("enter the number"))
c = "{}{}".format(a, b)
```

The `format` function takes objects as parameters and represent them by the `str` representation of the object.

In Python 3.6 and above, you can use the `f-string` that will do the same as `format` by adding an `f` before the string and the arguments inside like:

```
c = f'{a}{b}'
```

Both of the options will store the concatenation of `a` and `b` in `c`.

---

There is another option using the `print` function like:

```
print(a, b, sep="")
```

The `print` function takes all arguments separated by a `,` and prints the `str` representation of the objects - just like `format` does. The `sep` option of printing is by default a space that will print `" "` in between the arguments. By changing it to `""` it will print the arguments sequentially without space in between.

This option can be used without storing the concatenation of `a` and `b` in another variable as `c`.

Comment: If `c` is only calculated for printing, it is also possible to do instead `print(a, b, sep='')`

Comment: That's correct I just made the explanations to  store both values of int and string together in a variable.

Comment: Of course! You did it in a great way, just thought to add it as another option, not a critic to your answer at all

Comment: I'm adding tnx alot of the suggestion.

Comment: You explained good how to save it to a variable, as OP is doing in the question. I just meant, that in case that `c` is not really necessary and is only created for the `print`, this is a simpler alternative :)

Comment: My bad changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
a=input("enter the string value")
b=int(input("enter the number"))
c=a+str(b)
print(c)
```

Output

```
enter the string valuexyz
enter the number12
xyz12
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just **NOT** convert to `int` in the first place, as `input` already returns a string...

Comment: Sanity check for number

Answer (score 0):

If your final objectif is to concatenate, you don't realy need to convert your input to int, just use it as input:

```
a=input("enter the string value")
b=input("enter the number")
c=a+b
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `+` with strings, you can only concatenate it with other strings. However you were trying to concatenate it with an integer.

Change `c=a+b` to `c=a+str(b)`

`str(b)` converts `b` which is an integer to a string.