# TypeError: Can't convert int to str implicitly

Tags: python, typeerror

Im having trouble with this code Ive tried to fix it but I justt can't seem to figure out what the problem is can someone please help

```py
def main():

    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Welcome to the Movie Store!")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    budget = int(input("What is your budget?"))
    print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
    sale = (200 - budget)

    if(budget < 200):
        print("print("If you spend $" + sale + "you'll qualify for a gift!")
    else:
        print("You qualify for a free gift!")

main()
```

### Error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-65823cbb31f3> in <module>
      3 print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
      4 budget = int(input("What is your budget?"))
----> 5 print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
      6 sale = (200 - budget)
      7 

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Getting a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/getting-a-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Comment: Bypassing duplicate chain; Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate str and int objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675943/how-can-i-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `budget` with `str(budget)` in `print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")`.

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

You can't join together a string and `budget` which is an integer.

Change:

```
print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
```

To:

```
print("Your budget is " + str(budget) + "$.")
```

Comment: I tried this but it keeps saying the same error message

Answer (score 1):

def main():

```
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Welcome to the Movie Store!")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
budget = int(input("What is your budget?"))
print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
sale = (200 - budget)

if(budget < 200):
    print("print("If you spend $" + sale + "you'll qualify for a gift!")
else:
    print("You qualify for a free gift!")
```

main()

You are getting this error because you didn't convert the budget from int to string before printing. 
As we can only concatenate a string to a string .

They are many ways like:

1》Convert budget to str before printing:

```
   print("Your budget is " + str(budget) + "$.")
```

2》Use formatting in str:

```
 print("Your budget is  {} $" .format(budget))
```

3》Use f-string :

```
 print(f"Your budget is {budget} $.")
```

You have used print here 2times and here you also have to convert sale to string before printing using any of the above mentioned ways:

```
if(budget < 200):
    print("print("If you spend $" + sale + "you'll qualify for a gift!")
else:
    print("You qualify for a free gift!")
```

Hope you found this solution useful ...!!

Answer (score 0):

```
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Welcome to the Movie Store!")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
budget = input("What is your budget?")
print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
budget = int(budget)
sale = (200 - budget)

if(budget < 200):
    print("If you spend")
else:
    print("You qualify for a free gift!")
```

You don't need to switch budget to a variable right away since you are going to print it right after the input( You can't print strings with integer's). So i changed it to convert to an integer right before the program needs it. Hope this Helps You!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to concatenating is to use f-strings. I found [these examples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-specify-the-location-of-expressions-in-f-strings) in the documentation to be quite useful.

```
print(f"Your budget is {budget}$.")
```

Here, the `budget` variable can be of type `str`, `int`, or any other data type that can be casted into a string.

The benefit of using f-strings is that you don't have to worry about type conversions at all. Python will do them for you. You can even use results returned from function calls as well.

```
# Sample code
print(f"This length of this list is {len(lst)}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
print("Your budget is ",budget,"$.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message provides some useful information. It will even tell you exactly where the error happened. In this case, it tells you there is a `TypeError` on `line 5`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\deleteme\deleteme.py", line 5, in <module>
    print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

If you scroll to line 5, you'll see that it is:

```
print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
```

So, the problem is that you are trying to add the types `str + int + str`. That doesn't work. You'll have to convert the int to a string. Think of it like `str + str(int) + str`, or in your code:

```
print("Your budget is " + str(budget) + "$.")
```

Alternatively, the way I would do it is by using 'f-strings'. You just need to put an `f` before the first quotation mark, and your variables into curly braces (`{}`). This way, you won't even need to use `str()`:

```
print(f"Your budget is {budget} $.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use formated string in python:
You can use strng + int + strng this is not a method to print in python you can print by formated string like :
print(f"Your budget is {budget }$.")