# Error says TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, string, smtp, int

Im not sure what went wrong with the loop as it says [TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str] particularly on this line -> `msg.body = "Hi.. " + roll_id[i] + " is present for the lecture of " + "Prof. " +str(teacher_name.split('.',1)[0]) + ", which is held on " + excel_date + "@" + time + "hrs"` . Any ideas?

```py
    for i in range(len(roll_id)):
        cursor.execute("SELECT student_email,parent_email from student_login where binary roll_id=%s",[roll_id[i]])
        email = list(cursor.fetchone())
        print(type(email[1]))
        print(email[0])
        print(email[1])
        msg = Message('Auto Generated',recipients= [email[0],email[1]])
        msg.body = "Hi.. " + roll_id[i] + " is present for the lecture of " + "Prof. " +str(teacher_name.split('.',1)[0]) + ", which is held on " + excel_date + "@" + time + "hrs"
        msg.html = "Hi.. " + roll_id[i] + " is present for the lecture of " + "Prof. " +str(teacher_name.split('.',1)[0])+ ", which is held on " + excel_date + "@" + time + "hrs"
        mail.send(msg)
    return "<h1>mail sent<h1>"
```

Comment: Please complete your question for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Please search before asking a question.
[How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

[TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045632/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str-what-does-this-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Simply put - you need to cast `roll_id[i]` to a string.
You have casted `"teacher_name.split('.',1)[0]"` but not `"roll_id[i]"`. If `"excel_date"` and `"time"` are not strings, they'll need to be casted as well.