# Python coding, getting an error : can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, class, object, anaconda

```
class person:
        
    def __init__(self, name, age):
            self.name = name
            self.name = age
            
    def myfunc(self):
        print(" Hello my name is " + self.name)
        print(" my age is " + self.age)
p1 = person("Siddu", 24)
p1.myfunc() 
                
#p1 = person("siddu", 24)    
                
#print(p1.name)
#print(p1.age)
```

Comment: Hi, as the error message says, you can't "sum" strings and integers with `+`, so try `"age is" + str(self.age)` i.e. convert int to str first; or better yet, look into `f-strings`.

Comment: The error itself is self-explanatory, you are trying to concatenate string with integer..

Comment: What purpose does `self.name = age` have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

- you made one mistake in the init
- you should cast your numeric value as a string before concatenating

You can find the answer in the python comments

```
class person:
        
    def __init__(...):
            ...
            self.name = age #should be self.age = age
            
    def myfunc(self):
        ...
        print(" my age is " + self.age) #change self.age by str(self.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.name = age`
you should have `self.age = age`