# Python TypeError: can only concatenate str to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's wrong with this code snippet?

```
print('Podaj jakiś tekst')
x=input()
print('ten tekst ma'+(len(x))+'znaków')
```

Output is:

```
Podaj jakiś tekst
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\48573\PycharmProjects\niewiem\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print('ten tekst ma'+(len(x))+'znaków')
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is there anything unclear about the given message?

Comment: ```print('ten tekst ma'+str(len(x))+'znaków')``` may be this will fix issue because ```len()``` returns ```int``` value so you have to convert it into ```str``` type

Comment: function len don't count x

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `len()` returns an `int`, not a `str` (string). Change the last line to this:

```py
print('ten tekst ma'+str((len(x)))+'znaków')
```

Or use [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```py
print(f"ten tekst ma{len(x)}znaków")
```

Here are both examples:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20)
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=input()
asdf
>>> print('ten tekst ma'+str((len(x)))+'znaków')
ten tekst ma4znaków
>>> print(f"ten tekst ma{len(x)}znaków")
ten tekst ma4znaków
```

Note that the number 4, which is the number of characters in the input I provided, appears in both outputs.

Comment: first way Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\48573\PycharmProjects\niewiem\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print('ten tekst ma'+str((len(x)))+'znaków')
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Comment: I added examples for both possibilities, to show how they work.