# How to print elements with variables as the index

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

How would I print an element inside a for loop using its index?

```
flag = "T"
while flag == "T":
  x = []
  y = []
  x1 = int(input())
  y1 = int(input())
  x.append(x1)
  y.append(y1)
  for i in range(len(x)): 
    v = len(x)-1
    print(x[v])
    print("First value: " + x[v] + "\r\n" + "Second value: " + y[v])
```

The main question is that printing x with the index of v works in the first print call, but not the second. Why?

Comment: [TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str) YOu have recive a error when you run this program. i suggest you to go through that first

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print integers. Wrap it in `str()` to be able to print them:

```
flag = "T"
while flag == "T":
  x = []
  y = []
  x1 = int(input())
  y1 = int(input())
  x.append(x1)
  y.append(y1)
  for i in range(len(x)): 
    v = len(x)-1
    print(x[v])
    print("First value: " + str(x[v]) + "\r\n" + "Second value: " + str(y[v]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t bother trying to concatenate elements together only to print them. Use the ability of print to print all its arguments.

```py
print("First value: ", x[v], "\r\nSecond value: ", y[v])
```