# Construct file path using for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, data-analysis, string-concatenation

I am trying to write a function that reads an array of parquet files as dataframe and concatenate them sequentially as on file

```py
# Get the list of all files and directories
path = "C:**********\\main_data_1"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
dir_list
Total_df = []
all_ais_msg_df = []
for j in np.arange(1,len(dir_list)+1):
    filename = 'ais_comb_'+ str(j)+ '.parquet'
    j +=1
    Total_df.append(filename)


for i in Total_df:
   ** df = pd.read_parquet('main_data_1/'+ str(i))** # having problem here 
    i+=1
    all_ais_msg_df = pd.DataFrame(all_ais_msg_df.append(df))
```

I intend to construct a string like this ------>'main_data_1/ais_comb_1.parquet' while using the i in the second loop to increment ais_comb_1, ais-comb_2 aspect of the string until the last filename in order to get and combine all as a dataframe

The error I get is:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I crave a very clear explanation please, I am still a rookie.

Comment: Always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Not entirely sure about the error due to lack of stacktrace. Can you try 
"main_data_1/{}".format(i)

Comment: Also maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str

Comment: `j += 1` doesn't do anything useful; `j` will just be assigned the next value from the `arange` object.