# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module> print(name + age) TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, string, integer, typeerror

I was writing the above code when I encountered an error can you help me?

```py
name = 'mahbod'
age = 12
print(name + age)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(name + age)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: `age` needs to be of type `str`. Try `print(name + str(age))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to define two different variables: `name` and `age`.
In that case, you need to define each of them on a different line:

```py
name = "mahbod"
age = 12
```

otherwise, here Python thinks that you are defining `name` as `"Mahbod" age`.
In python, you can concatenate strings by separating them with a space, like this:

```py
>>> string = "Hello " "world"
>>> print(string)
Hello world
```

so that's what Python is trying to do here, except that `age` is not a string, but a variable that you defined as 12, hence the confusion