# What is wrong in this simple code with if?

Tags: python

I'm learning python and i am doing a simple ecerxice exactly the same that the teacher (youtube), (he is correct in his run, varibales "Nombre" is a str, and "Promedio" is a int as well), but for me result an error. Thank you in advance

The code:

```
print("Sistema particular para calcular el promedio de un alumno")

Nombre = input("Para comenzar, cual es su nombre?: ")

Matemáticas = int(input(Nombre + " cual es tu calificación de matemáticas?: "))
Química = int(input(Nombre + " cual es tu calificación de química?: "))
Biología = int(input(Nombre + " cual es tu calificación de biología?: "))

Promedio = (Matemáticas + Química + Biología) // 3


if Promedio >= 6:
    print("Felicidades " + Nombre + " ’aprobaste’ con un promedio de: " + Promedio)

print("Fin.")
```

#the error is:

```
print("Felicidades " + Nombre + " ’aprobaste’ con un promedio de: " + Promedio)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Varibales "Nombre" is a str, and "Promedio" is a int, exactly as the teacher in his video. But for me is an error.

Comment: Please add the link to the youtube video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says you cant concatenate str with int, therefore try use :

```
print("Felicidades " + Nombre + " ’aprobaste’ con un promedio de: " + str(Promedio))
```

Comment: It worked just with that! Thank you Ugur!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve your issue. The most practical way would be to use f-string or s-string formatting, as shown below.

**F String**

```
print(f"Felicidades {Nombre}  ’aprobaste’ con un de: {Promedio}")
```

---

**S String**

```
print("Felicidades %s ’aprobaste’ con un promedio de: %s" % (Nombre, Promedio))
```

---

### F vs S

**F-String:**

- More readable due to the variable names being contained where they will appear inside the string.
- Variables are evaluated where string is declared, making it less reusable.

**S-String:**

- Slightly less readable.
- Variables are evaluated where string is called, meaning that the string can de used as a template.

---

**Python Docs:**

[printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)