# Python Beginner lerning len

Tags: python, string, string-length

I am doing some exercises, and I am a beginner in python. Doing some coding challenge and there was an exercise that tells me I should ask my name, and it should show me how many letters my name has.

**My first solution was:**

```
name = "What is your Name?"
print("Your Name has: " + len(name) + " Letters.")
```

**It showed me an error.**

Why was my first solution wrong? I mean, I learned a bit of Java it's a bit different, but shouldn't it normally print it out?
Would be nice if someone had different solutions or maybe a little answer for me.
Would be awesome, thanks.

**I changed the len(name) into str(len(name)).**

```
name = "What is your Name?"
print("Your Name has: " + str(len(name)) + " Letters.")
```

**that worked.**

but why my first solution didn't worked?

Comment: Did you read an error that it gave you?

Comment: Unrelated: your code assumes that the user is named `What is your Name?`, rather than actually asking the user what their name is.

Comment: In First  code you are adding `int` to `string` therefore in your second code when you `typecast`  it to `string`  it worked. you can use f-strings like `print(f'Your name has {len(name)} letters')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252580/how-to-resolve-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str)

Answer (score 2):

In java, every primitive type has an innate string-like wrapper that kicks in when you build a string using different components and the `+` operator.

That convention isn't adopted in python.

There are different ways to build a string in python, the simplest, using the `+` operator, requires all components be cast to strings, as you have discovered.

I'd also recommend looking at the string [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) function, as well as [f-strings](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-f-strings-tutorial-how-to-use-f-strings-for-string-formatting/) which is an alternative.

For a more rounded, general information source, try the python [Input and Output docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Well said. Totally agree

Comment: Okay understand. In java will be too everything declared thats a bit different in python, didnt thought that much about it. So if i want to use a int in a string i need to format it or use f-string. Will be looking into it thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot append a number to a string:
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Better to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```py
>>> print(f"Your Name has: {len(name)} Letters.")
Your Name has: 18 Letters.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will be looking into f-string :)

Answer (score 0):

`Java` and `Python` are different languages. Java has a String concatenate that will "promote" an `int` to a `String`.

```
name = "What is your Name?"
    print("Your Name has: " + len(name) + " Letters.")
```

In your first code your `len(name)` is an `int` type and your trying to concatenate into a `string` which throws error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Python works a bit differently, the value you are concatenating needs to be same type, both `int` or `str.`
To concatenate a string and a number, such as an integer int or a floating point number float , you first need to convert the number to a string with `str()` . Then, you can use the `+` or `+=` operator to concatenate.

but you can also use `f-string`. `f-strings` provide a concise and convenient way to embed python expressions inside string literals for formatting.like this

```
name = str(input("what is your name ?"))
print(f"Your Name has: {len(name)} Letters.")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Explanation. I  know they are 2 different languages, sure. I was just a bit confused about the operator, thought it would be the same like in Java, but forgot in java you need to declare everything and in python is seems like everything a string. 

I got a long road to go, but i like :) python it makes fun to code.  So i need to convert everything in python. Thanks for the explanation, i will read into f-string.

Answer (score 0):

- In your First Code you are adding `int` to `str`, this is `TypeError` in Python, Therefore when you typecast it to `str(len(name))` it works.
- Use f-string. so you don't have to concatenate the strings like

  `print(f'Your name has: {len(name)} letters')`

Answer (score 0):

For example take this **input**:

```
name = 'What is your name?'  # This crates stringVar 
print(len(name))             # This works because Python can easily print integer
print(len(name) + 25)        # Python can also print math functions
try:
    print('My name is ' + len(name) + 'letter long')  # But this here is called concatenation which must be created with strings -> that's why the error
except TypeError as er:
    print(er)
print(f'My name is {len(name)} letters long')         # This works because this is f-string
```

The **output**:

[image]

[What is f-string?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

If you want the name to be really interactive use it like this:

`name = input('What is your name:\t')`